# Conditionally selecting values on mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   products_id   |   net_price  |  special_price  |  special_expire  | special_status
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1            |      500     |     200         |  2012-5-03 00:00 |      1
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    2            |      600     |     300         |  2012-6-04 00:00 |      0
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3            |      700     |     400         |  2012-7-05 00:00 |      1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Where `products_id`, `net_price`, `special_price`, `special_expire` is self explanatory and `special_status` defines `1` as to apply the special price and `0` as to disable the special price.

I have a search form wherein there is a price range.

```
<form method="get" action="http://website.com">
    <input type="text" id="ref-search" name="search" value="<?php echo  $search_value;?>" class="text" size="55" placeholder="Type a keyword." style="height: 30px;
    width: 89%;">

<label>Price Range:</label><br>
<span class="price-range">
From <input type="text" id="price1" name="pricefrom" 
     value="<?php echo $pricefrom_value; ?>" class="text" style="
     height: 20px;
     width: 22%;"> 

to   <input type="text" id="price2" name="priceto" 
     value="<?php echo $priceto_value; ?>" class="text" style="
     height: 20px;
     width: 22%;">
</form>
```

I'm having a hard time developing or finding a solution to conditionally select `net_price` if either `special_price` is `0.000`, the `special_expire` date value has passed or the `special_status`'s value is `0`. Then if there is a value in the `special_price`, `special_expire` date value hasn't passed and the `special_status`'s value is `1` then select the `special_price` value.

This is the picture that i want to come from. ( I know that this is not possible but, i guess this is the best way to picture out my problem. )

```
    $sql = "select products_id, products_price, special_price, special_expire,  
            special_status, products_name from " . TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS . "  where
            products_name like '%" . $search_key . "%' 

    and /**Where the condition starts**/ 

    if(special_value is =="0.000" || special_expire == <EXPIRED> || 
       special_status =="0") {
       products_price >= ".$pricefrom_key." and products_price <= ".$priceto_key."
    } else {
       specials_new_products_price >= ".$pricefrom_key." 
       and specials_new_products_price <= ".$priceto_key." order by products_name
    }";
```

I hope you can help me guys..
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT products_id, products_price, special_price, special_expire, 
special_status, products_name, 
case when (special_price > 0 and special_expire > Now() and special_status != 0) 
then special_price else net_price end price from " . TABLE_GLOBAL_PRODUCTS . " 
where products_name like '%" . $search_key . "%' 
having price >= ".$pricefrom_key." and price <= ".$priceto_key.";
```

Make sure you escape your inputs!